# How to automatically archive and label "everything else" in Gmail priority inbox

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I want everything else to skip the inbox, so I'm left with only the important messages in my inbox.

I’d also like to label “everything else” so I can check it daily for anything that is important. Currently, I can’t find a way to do this.

Is this possible? And if yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

The first part of your question, I can answer off the top of my head. There's an option with regards to Priority Inbox to litteraly only show important messages.

Go to `Settings` - `Inbox`. There you can arrange the `Inbox sections` to only show important messages.

Comment: Hi @pleinolijf. could you expand on this method, as from what i see, the "everything else" cannot be turned off in the settings.

Comment: I checked again, and you are correct. Since all other types of sections could be hidden, I assumed the same for "everything else", which is the only one that **can't** be hidden. My bad !